# How to use SPARQL to query a ttl file?

Tags: python, sparql, rdf, rdflib

I am trying to learn SPARQL and to do that I need to execute queries against a local ttl file.  I have researched this and every response says to use `rdflib` and then run a query against that.

Here is the example ttl file I am using

```
# filename: ex002.ttl

@prefix ab: <http://learningsparql.com/ns/addressbook#> .

ab:richard ab:homeTel "(229) 276-5135" . 
ab:richard ab:email   "richard49@hotmail.com" . 

ab:cindy ab:homeTel "(245) 646-5488" . 
ab:cindy ab:email   "cindym@gmail.com" . 

ab:craig ab:homeTel "(194) 966-1505" . 
ab:craig ab:email   "craigellis@yahoo.com" . 
ab:craig ab:email   "c.ellis@usairwaysgroup.com" .
```

Now the python code that is supposed to work is the following

```
filename = "C:/DataStuff/SemanticOntology/LearningSPARQLExamples/ex002.ttl" 
import rdflib
g = rdflib.Graph()

result = g.parse(filename, format='ttl')
print(result)
query = """
SELECT * WHERE {
        ?s ?p ?o .
}
"""

g.query(query)
for stmt in g:
    print(stmt)
```

Unfortunately whenever it gets to `g.query(query)` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rdfextras'`

Okay - no problem.  So I go to conda-forge to install it, and it says that package is not available from current channels.

Okay, weird.  So I do some research and discover https://github.com/RDFLib/rdfextras
which says it is discontinued and it is no longer required for `rdflib` `>=4`.  So I check my version of `rdflib` and it is `4.2.2`.  So obviously something is wrong, since it shouldn't require `rdfextras`.

So two questions -

1. Why is it doing this if my version of `rdflib >=4`?
2. Ultimately - this is all beside the point.  I don't care about the means, so how do I use python to run SPARQL queries against local ttl files (in a way that doesn't require admin rights on my computer)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"so how do I use python to run SPARQL queries against local ttl files"* - with `rdflib` - this is by far the most common library for RDF/SPARQL written in Python.

Comment: And I can't reproduce your problem. I did `pip install rdflib` and then simply used it. maybe you have multiple versions of the package on your system? Do you use `virtualenv` or the like? How do you run your code? From an IDE or via commandline?

Comment: To install libraries I use a command prompt and then enter conda install -c conda-forge rdflib.  To actually run the code I use spyder with anaconda.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize - I just got home and re-ran the query and now it seems to be working. I have no idea what changed between now and about 2 hours ago

Comment: Now you should accept your own answer, or simply delete your question, as it seems to have been a no-op...

Comment: Voting up your answer is not the same as [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) it...

Comment: I agree - I should delete this post, but I don't see any way to do that.  At best I can "vote" to delete it.  So what is the etiquette here?

Comment: To delete the question, you'll need to first downvote (or delete) your answer. Then you should see a link that lets you delete the question, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions).